# TransactionScope and BeginTransaction

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6

In EF6, MVC, MySQL scenario, what is the difference between using  EF `TransactionScope` and `DBContext.BeginTransaction`?  There is no explicit rollback in `TransactionScope`.

Should it be

```
using transactionscope
{
   using dbContext
   {
        .........
        .........
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        .............
        .......
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
   }
   transactionscope.Complete();
  // there is no .Rollback method
}
```

Or

```
using dbContext
{
   using dbtx = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction
   {
        .........
        .........
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        .............
        .......
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        dbtx.Commit()
        // and dbtx.Rollback()  when exception occurs
   }

}
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I would not pay attention to the difference.  I would not worry about isolation level.  The following works:  either all rollsback (no explicit rollback necessary) or all commits:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    ...
    db.SaveChanges();

    ...
    db.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```